# Need help with solving equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to solve for $x$ in the equations

$$a=e^{-x}(m(1+x+x^2/2+x^3/3)-x^3/3)$$

and

$$a=e^{-x}(m(1+x+x^2/2+x^3/3+x^4/4)-x^4/4)$$

or even with more terms. Here $a$ is some constant.

Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: Do you mean that $x$ is to satisfy both of these equations (so simultaneous equations)? I would guess not, and in that case I would expect no simple closed form solutions, but only a numerical method for given $a,m$ could be applied.

Answer (score 2):

Even the simpler problem $a=e^{-x}(m(1+x)-x)$ (assuming $m\ne1$) can only be solved for $x$ by introducing the Lambert $W$-function, which you are invited to look up.

Comment: yep, that's the simplest case, but with more terms, it gets harder to solve.